# Inserção de ponto a cada 5 caracteres

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte string: "AAAAABBBBBCCCCC"

Existe um script que coloca um ponto "." a cada 5 caracteres?
No caso esse script retornaria: "AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma solução é a função [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/chunk_split) que serve precisamente para dividir a *string* em pedaços mais pequenos:

```
$str = chunk_split("AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD", 5, '.');
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eH5QL1):

```
var_dump($str); // AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.
```

<sup>**Nota:** Estou a sugerir esta função porque na tua pergunta pedias não só adicionar o `.` a cada X posições, mas para o resultado terminar com `.`. Com esta função, satisfazes ambos os requisitos.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
    $string = "AAAAABBBBBCCCCC";
    $array = str_split($string, 5); 
    $novaString = implode(".", $array);
    echo $novaString;
?>
```

Explicando o que acontece: Você separou a string em várias Strings, e guardou-as dentro de uma array chamada $array. O resultado disso é:

> $array[0] possui os valores AAAAA
>
> $array[1] possui os valores BBBBB
>
> $array[2] possui os valores CCCCC

E após a separação nas arrays usa-se o implode para concatenar as strings armazenadas na array com o ponto (.). Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: O problema é que `str_split` não aceita multibyte, mas se a string não contiver acentos, essa resposta é mais direta.

Comment: To ligado @PapaCharlie, já precisei de uma solução dessa e me serviu uma vez por justamente não ter acentos, como ele não especificou. Sua resposta também está muito boa por tratar desse detalhe.

Comment: Mas oq é multibyte?

Comment: @NickolasCarlos, muitas idiomas conseguem comportar um caractere em apenas 1 byte, mas existem outros que não conseguem, no caso do português existem caracteres que são acentuados, por exemplo: ÁÃÓÒ entre vários outros, para armazenar esses tipos de caracteres são necessários mais que apenas 1 byte. Então caracteres que precisam de mais de 1 byte para serem armazenados são chamados multibyte.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma de adicionar uma string baseada em um intervalo(5 caracteres) é utilizar a função [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). O terceiro parâmetro é o caracter a ser inserido e o quarto força o php a **adicionar o caracter no intervalo exato**, porque o objetivo da função é fazer a adição entre palavaras e como sua string é uma coisa só o quarto parâmetro torn-se obrigatório.

```
$str = "AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD";
$intervalo = 5;
$str_formatada = wordwrap($str, $intervalo, '.', true);

echo $str_formatada;
```

Saída:

```
AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD
```

**[phpfiddle - exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yg59-urac)**

---

Exemplo do quarto parâmetro:

1 - Omitido

```
$str = 'A very long woooooooooooord';
$str_formatada = wordwrap($str, 3, "<br>");

echo $str_formatada;
```

Saída:

```
A
very
long
woooooooooooord
```

Como as palavras era menores ou maiores que o intervalo especificado(3) a função acabou fazendo a adição de `<br>` entre elas. Veja como funciona quando o quarto parâmentro é marcado como true, agora a string é quebrada a exatamente 3 caracteres mesmo isso corte ou estrague a palavra.

2- Com o quarto parâmetro

Saída:

```
A
ver
y
lon
g
woo
ooo
ooo
ooo
ord
```

Answer (score 4):

Já que levantaram a lebre sobre *multibyte*, vou deixar uma alternativa com tal suporte:

```
$string = 'aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeee1111122222maçãsefeijões';

$new = implode(

    '.',

    preg_split(

        '/(.{5})/us',

       $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    )
);
```

Isso produz:

```
string 'aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd.eeeee.11111.22222.maçãs.efeij.ões' (length=60)
```

Comment: O que seria "levantaram a lebre" @BrunoAugusto?

Comment: +1 pelo suporte ao multibyte

Comment: [**Qual a origem e o significado da frase «levantaram a lebre»?**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5304/8) (cc @WallaceMaxters)