# Como dividir uma string com delimitador em PHP?

Tags: php, string, concatenação-de-string

tenho uma string

**"1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6"**

e quero dividí-la dessa forma:

**"1b00bd51-5bf8cbc5-a86f3b71-4361fab6"**

COMO FAÇO?

Comment: Outras opções de como adicionar um carácter em um intervalo especifico http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44639/91

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizando a função [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) para criar um *array* da sua *string* separando a cada 8 caracteres e [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) para juntar usando um delimitador, tente algo assim:

```
$str = "1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6";
echo implode('-', str_split($str, 8));
```

Saída:

> 1b00bd51-5bf8cbc5-a86f3b71-4361fab6

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6";  
print_r(preg_replace('/(\w{8})(?=\w)/', '$1-', $str));
```