# Qual é a forma mais simples para criar uma máscara para números em PHP?

Tags: php, formatação

Eu tenho duas maneiras de criar máscaras para números em PHP, porém não sei se é a mais elegante e eficaz, por isso gostaria de opniões para melhorar o código.

Preciso que a função se comporte da seguinte forma:

- Formate os números com menos de 8 números preenchendo-os com `zero`.
- Crie um separador (pode ser um hífen) no meio desses 8 números. Ou seja, `11112222` transformará em `1111-2222`.

Tenho já esses dois exemplos:

Exemplo 1:

```
implode('-', str_split(sprintf('%08s', $numero), 4));
```

Exemplo 2

```
$formatado = sprintf('%08s', $numero);

substr($formatado, 0, 4) . '-' . substr($formatado, 4, 8);
```

Alguém sabe uma maneira melhor, em termos de performance e elegância, sem ter que chamar várias funções para criar uma máscara em PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso, é combinar [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) para preencher os zeros a esquerda* caso a string tenha menos que 8 caracteres, [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) para inserir o hifen a cada 4 caracteres e o [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) para remover o hifen adicionado no final.

```
<?php

function mascaraTelefone($numero){
    $numero = str_pad($numero, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return trim(chunk_split($numero, 4, '-'), '-');
}

echo mascaraTelefone('9999') .PHP_EOL;
echo mascaraTelefone('99998888') .PHP_EOL;
echo mascaraTelefone('77') .PHP_EOL;
echo mascaraTelefone('666') .PHP_EOL;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/ocdu7g)

Baseado em: [Inserção de ponto a cada 5 caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44639/91)

Uma variante desse código é trocar `chunck_split()` por [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) que substitui uma cópia do caracter que está na posição X(terceiro argumento) pelo hifen no caso.

```
function mascaraTelefone($numero){
    $numero = str_pad($numero, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return substr_replace($numero, '-', 4, 0);
}
```

* O comportamento padrão de `str_pad()` é adicionar os caracteres a direita, isso pode ser modificado ao informar o quarto argumento da função 
que possuiu os valores:

```
STR_PAD_RIGHT|Adiciona a direita(padrão caso o quarto argumento seja omitido
STR_PAD_LEFT |Adiciona a esquerda
STR_PAD_BOTH |Adiciona na esquerda e na direita
```

Comment: quem é esse tal de `chunk_split`!? não me lembro dele

Comment: Ooooh! Que legal! Muito bacana, esse `chunk_split`!

Comment: Acho que vou adotar o `str_pad` também. Toda vez eu tenho que ficar utilizando o `sprintf` com aquela concatenação feia `"0{$size}s%"`.

Comment: No caso não deveria ter indicado no str_pad o pad_type como STR_PAD_LEFT? Por padrão será preenchido à direita do valor.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade bem lembrado, eu troquei o código e a explicação da resposta xD

Answer (score 6):

Formatação genérica com máscara dinâmica:

```
function format_string($mask, $str, $ch = '#') {
    $c = 0;
    $rs = '';

    /*
    Aqui usamos strlen() pois não há preocupação com o charset da máscara.
    */
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($mask); $i++) {
        if ($mask[$i] == $ch) {
            $rs .= $str[$c];
            $c++;
        } else {
            $rs .= $mask[$i];
        }
    }

    return $rs;
}

$str = '05055344410'; // Exemplo para telefone
echo format_string('###-####-####', $str);
$str = '20150827'; // Exemplo para datas
echo '<br />' . format_string('####-##-##', $str);
```

Comment: A princípio eu pensei que seria muito código (em relação ao código do @rray). Mas reparei que a sua funcionalidade está parecida com o `jQuery.mask`, e isso é muito bom

Comment: O ponto que julgo mais interessante é a flexibilidade. Permite-se formatar strings para múltiplos propósitos, não somente números de telefones localizados. A inspiração não vem de JQuery, é um script que uso desde 2000 ou 1999. Não lembro. Nessa época não tinha stack, google, jquery. Era na raça mesmo. 
Em muitos casos, o tamanho do código não significa melhor desempenho. Na primeira resposta há o uso de 3 funções. Dentro dessas 3 funções há todo um processamento, laços de repetição, talvez também uso de ER, etc. Teoricamente usa muito mais códigos. Isso custa mais processamento e memória.

Answer (score 2):

Já está muito bem respondido, mas eu gostaria de deixar aqui uma pequena técnica que usa `vsprintf` e `str_split` juntos.

A função `vsprintf` tem como finalidade formatar uma string, baseando-se nos argumentos passados. Porém diferente de `sprintf`, ao invés de passar `n` parâmetros, você passa um `array`. Sendo assim, poderíamos, utilizar a função `str_split` para separar as strings e, com `vsprintf`, aplicar a formatação.

Nesse exemplo, passei um segundo argumento para `str_split`, que fará que a string seja dividida de 4 em 4, como é o caso dos telefones.

```
function formatar_telefone($telefone) {
     return vsprintf('%s-%s', str_split($telefone, 4));
}
```

É claro que haverá problemas caso o número do telefone não contenha 8 dígitos. Então nesse caso, pode ser adicionar uma verificação dentro da função, com um lançamento de um erro ou exceção. Ou basta apenas preencher os valores com `0`, como o @rray sugeriu.

Nesse caso, poderíamos preencher usando `sprintf` para preencher com zeros, através da expressão `%08d`:

```
function formatar_telefone($telefone) {
     vsprintf('%s-%s%', str_split(sprintf('%08d', $telefone)));
}
```

A expressão `%08d` significa que você quer formatar um número, forçando a ser reconhecido como um dígito, e, caso tenha menos que 8 caracteres, será preenchido com `0`.