# Mask - Mascara javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estava transcrevendo algumas funções que tenho no PHP para o javascript.
Como eu poderia deixar este código mais eficiente ?

```
String.prototype.substrCount = function(str){
    if(str == undefined){
        return 0;
    }
    var r = new RegExp(str, 'g');
    return (this.match(r) || []).length;
}

String.prototype.mask = function(mask){
    var value = onlyNumber(this);   // REMOVE TUDO QUE NAO SEJA NUMERO

    for(var i = 0; i <= mask.substrCount('#'); i++){

        if(typeof(value[i]) === 'undefined'){
            break;
        } 

        var k = mask.indexOf('#');  // CAPTURA O PROXIMO INDICE DE #
        mask = mask.split('');
        mask[k] = value[i];
        mask = mask.join('');
    }

    return mask;
}
```

No PHP eu tenho ele simplesmente assim :

```
function maskNumber($mask,$str){
    $str = onlyNumber($str);    // REMOVE TUDO QUE NAO SEJA NUMERO

    $count = mb_substr_count($mask, '#');
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $mask[strpos($mask,"#")] = $str[$i];
    }

    return $mask;
}
```

Comment: Como é o funcionamento dessa função ? Substitui `#` por números, é isso ?

Comment: Sim, basicamente '72081338831'.mask('###.###.###-##') = 720.813.388-31

Comment: Veja se [essa respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82687/91) ajuda.

Comment: @rray era essa pergunta que eu estava procurando faz um tempo.

Comment: Essa pergunta não o contrario do que vc quer? agora que notei LOL

Comment: Sim, mas fazia um tempo eu estava querendo montar a do PHP e não achei, ai pesquisei mais e achei essa, mas agora estou querendo transcrever para o JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escrevi algo abaixo que vai te auxiliar, mas acho melhor utilizar alguma biblioteca para mask, [em jquery](https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/), [em angular](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask), [js puro](http://www.cssscript.com/lightweight-pure-javascript-input-mask/).

Abaixo segue o código embutido e no plunker:
[mask code no plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mHd323v0dSw0Os6qe4Cp?p=preview)

```js
String.prototype.mask = function(mask){
    var result = '';
    var value = this.replace(/\D/g, '');   // REMOVE TUDO QUE NAO SEJA NUMERO

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < mask.length; i++) { 
      if (mask[i] == '#') {
        result += value[j] ? value[j] : '';
        j++;
      } else {
        result += mask[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
}

document.getElementById('xpto').innerHTML = '72081338831'.mask('###.###.###-##');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="xpto">initial value</div>    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: De fato creio que transcrever a string seja melhor que explodir e unir, mas vou aguardar mais um pouco. Obrigado.