# Duvida Data com PHP e JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, data

Oi não conheço nada de JS e gostaria de saber se tem como eu editar um campo cujo valor veio do banco de dados usando javascript?
Porque eu salvei no banco a data de nascimento e o telefone de um cliente,e no momento do cadastro eu salvo o telefone sem a mask e a data no padrão Ano-Mês-Dia.

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar js para formatar esses valores vindos do banco para que seja exibido assim telefone (99) 99999-9999 e data 99/99/9999.

Obs : Só fiz essa pergunta porque não consegui encontrar nada no google.

Answer (score 3):

O que você procura são expressões regulares, através delas você pode encontrar e modificar partes de strings:

Exemplificando:
Eu tenho o valor do banco impresso na página:

```
<p class="phone">1199999999</p>
```

Modificando o texto dentro da tag p:

```
 $(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
    text = text.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    return text;
});
```

Exemplo online no JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsh9modu/1/

Mais sobre expressões regulares em javascript: https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/04/expressoes-regulares-em-javascript/

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos e principalmente ao  Eduardo Kawanaka, consegui resolver o problema usando essas expressões que ele indicou.

Answer (score 1):

Formatação genérica com máscara dinâmica:

```js
function format_string(mask, str, ch) {
 ch = (typeof ch === "undefined") ? "#" : ch;
    var c = 0, r = "", l = mask.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) r += ((mask.substring(i, (i+1)) == ch) ? str.substring(c, ++c) : mask.substring(i, (i+1))); 
    return r;
}

str = '05055344410'; // Exemplo para telefone
document.write(format_string('###-####-####', str));

str = '20150827'; // Exemplo para datas
document.write("<br />"+format_string('####-##-##', str));

str = '100000'; // Exemplo para horário
document.write("<br />"+format_string('##:##:##', str));

str = '45564646456'; // Exemplo para cpf
document.write("<br />"+format_string('###.###.###-##', str));

str = '85282224448'; // Exemplo para qualquer outro formato, um telefone com código do país.
document.write("<br />"+format_string('+### ####-####', str));
```

A rotina é baseada numa outra resposta com PHP. Caso tenha interesse na função escrita em PHP, leia o post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82687/4793

Note que não necessita de bibliotecas ou plugins.