# Como se faz máscara para exibição de fone, cnpj, cpf, etc no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Sou iniciante em Laravel e gostaria de exibir campos como CPF, CNPJ e Fones formatadas como (xx) xxxxx-xxxx, etc.

Pesquisei e encontrei uma função que executaria isso (mask: http://blog.clares.com.br/php-mascara-cnpj-cpf-data-e-qualquer-outra-coisa/) mas não consegui inserir.

Comment: Você não salva os dados com a máscara?

Comment: Na verdade, não há nada específico sobre o Laravel, mas aqui no site há várias perguntas sobre como fazer em PHP

Comment: [Forma mais simples de colocar máscara em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82683/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-mais-simples-para-criar-uma-m%C3%A1scara-para-n%C3%BAmeros-em-php)

Comment: A função que vc referencia na pergunta já é excelente. Seu problema é **como fazê-la funcionar no `Laravel`**.

Comment: Isso pode ser feito facilmente em js aqui está uma biblioteca muito legal: [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: O mais fácil para sua questão seria formatar com Javascript com a biblioteca [https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 3):

Bem, como você quer exibir, então você tem duas opções:

- Formatar o valor antes de enviar para view;
- Formatar o valor na view
  usando JS.

Para formatar usando PHP o código que você mostrou já deve servir. Mas caso queira, de uma olhada na minha implementação para aplicar máscara para CPF, CNPJ e Telefone (é levado em conta que o valor só tenha números):

```
/**
* Formata uma string segundo a máscara de CPF
* caso o tamanho da string seja diferente de 11, a string será retornada sem formatação
* @param string $cpf
* @return string
*/
function cpf($cpf) {

   if (! $cpf) {

       return '';

   }

   if (strlen($cpf) == 11) {

       return substr($cpf, 0, 3) . '.' . substr($cpf, 3, 3) . '.' . substr($cpf, 6, 3) . '-' . substr($cpf, 9);

   }

   return $cpf;

}



    /**
     * Formata uma string segundo a máscara de CNPJ
     * caso o tamanho da string seja diferente de 14, a string será retornada sem formatação
     * @param $cnpj
     * @return string
     */
     function cnpj($cnpj) {

        if (! $cnpj) {

            return '';

        }

        if (strlen($cnpj) == 14) {

            return substr($cnpj, 0, 2) . '.' . substr($cnpj, 2, 3) . '.' . substr($cnpj, 5, 3) . '/' . substr($cnpj, 8, 4) . '-' . substr($cnpj, 12, 2);

        }

        return $cnpj;

    }

/**
 * Formata uma string segundo a máscara de telefone
 * caso o tamanho da string seja diferente de 10 ou 11, a string será retornada sem formatação
 * @param string $fone
 * @return string
 */
function fone($fone) {

    if (! $fone) {

        return '';

    }

    if (strlen($fone) == 10) {

        return '(' . substr($fone, 0, 2) . ')' . substr($fone, 2, 4) . '-' . substr($fone, 6);

    }

    if (strlen($fone) == 11) {

        return '(' . substr($fone, 0, 2) . ')' . substr($fone, 2, 5) . '-' . substr($fone, 7);

    }

    return $fone;

}
```

Caso você prefira usar uma biblioteca em JS, recomendo a InputmaskJS: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Você colocar o cpf, cnpj ou telefone em um input e então chama o método da biblioteca para aplicar uma máscara qualquer. No link do github que coloque acima existe uma série de exemplos que você pode seguir.

Comment: E para você validar os dados no back-end recomendo que use essa lib:

https://github.com/geekcom/validator-docs

Comment: O ruim é que quando o CPF começa com um zero, esse zero não é exibido.
Não sei por que.