# Formatar números de telefone e CNPJ

Tags: php

Estou quebrando a cabeça em como exibir números de telefone e CNPJ formatados através do PHP.

As minhas ideias são ou criar um script que ao preencher os pontos e traços são colocados automaticamente (estilo quando você preenche o CPF só com números e o site faz a pontuação automaticamente), qual linguagem eu deveria utilizar para isso?

Ou então a saída que penso ser mais fácil, no comando `echo` delimitar a pontuação através do comprimento da string, alguém saberia me indicar quais comandos eu deveria utilizar (pode ser só um norte, me digam que comando que faz isso que vou atrás de mais informações)?

Comment: Você quer uma máscara ao digitar ou apenas para exibir?

Comment: eu to querendo registrar esses dados num banco de dados local, pra posteriormente fazer um apanhado de dados e formar uma tabela.

Comment: Será que [isso ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82683/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-mais-simples-para-criar-uma-m%C3%A1scara-para-n%C3%BAmeros-em-php)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de diversas formas, vou lhe mostrar a mais simples. Existe uma biblioteca própria que você pode "Importar" através de link .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

adicione este script abaixo no seu HTML também

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#cpf').mask('00000-000');
      $('#cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');
      $('#telefone').mask('0000-0000');
    });
 </script>
```

E no seu input basta colocar o ID referente ao que indicou no JavaScript. Mas, também pode criar um class e referenciar por `$('.cpf').mask('00000-000);` porém, terá que alterar seu input e invés de id colocar `class='cpf'`

```
<input type='text' name='cpf' id='cpf'>

<input type='text' name='cnpj' id='cnpj'>

<input type='text' name='telefone' id='telefone'>
```

Lembrando que caso queira enviar diretamente para o banco de dados, nas suas variáveis terá que fazer uma tratativa para eliminar os pontos, vou deixar abaixo um exemplo simples de como deve ser feito.

```
$chars = array(".","/","-", "*"); /* aqui indico os caracteres que desejo remover */

$cpf = str_replace($chars, "", $_POST['cpf']); /* através de str_replace insiro somente os números invés de caracteres */
$cnpj = str_replace($chars, "", $_POST['cnpj']);
$telefone = str_replace($chars, "", $_POST['telefone']);
```

Comment: Conseguiu @MaicomRodeghiero ?

Comment: To tentando aplicar aqui, sou bem noob ainda, to recém no primeiro semestre de Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas. Mas to tentando desenvolver essa parada por fora pro meu trabalho aqui.
Assim que eu conseguir aplicar ele eu te aviso :)

Comment: basta seguir o passo a passo que te disse, copie e cole esses primeiros links, com a tag <script> e depois basta fazer como indiquei, que dará certo

Comment: A parte de remover os caracteres especiais ta funcionando perfeitamente! muito obrigado! Mas e pra eu puxar eles do DB e exibir formatados?

Comment: você já tem uma função para puxar estes dados do banco de dados através de select ? se sim coloque a mesma marcara depois dos campos porém ao invés de 0 preencha com 9

Comment: encontrei dois problemas, não sei se é questão noob minha ou se realmente tem problemas:
1º - $('.cpf').mask('00000-000); /* falta uma aspa no final
2º - $chars = array(".","/","-", "\", "*"); /* a barra invertida bugou o final do array.

Comment: o correto é colocar as aspas e deixar assim => $('.cpf') como eu fiz na resposta acima ... e retire a barra invertida

Comment: Resolvi a exibição com esse código:
`echo '('.substr($tel_contato, 0, 2).') '.substr($tel_contato, 2, 4).'-'.substr($tel_contato,6);`
Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: se tiver alguma outra dificuldade só comentar aqui

Comment: Tudo resolvido! Muito obrigado pelo tempo e atenção disposto!

Answer (score 1):

Crie um function em jQuery para validar o CPF e/ou CNPJ.
Caso não for algo apenas visual, terá que fazer o tratamento para salvar no banco de dados, dando os `.replace` nos pontos e barra.

Exemplo:

```
$(function () {
        $("[id$=txtCpfCnpj]").focusout(function () {
            $(this).unmask();
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ""));
        }).click(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "")).unmask();
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 11) {
                $(this).mask("999.999.999-99");
            } else if ($(this).val().length == 14) {
                $(this).mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Depois vou dar uma buscada nisso! valeu pela informação!
to tentando ele fazer funcionar como um todo primeiro, por último vou correr atrás da parte mais estética.

Valeu por dedicar seu tempo a me ajudar, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Eu ia dizer que jQuery para validar CPF e CNPJ é exagero, mas vi a aplicação de máscara no campo, então ok.